# Insert Freeform entries to Channel Entries

Tags: channel-entries, solspace-freeform, channel-form

I am setting up a form using FreeForm.  I would like user-submitted entries to be sent as a Channel Entry.  Is this possible?  I know that I can use the {exp:channel:form} tag to set this up, but I'd prefer having the backend features of Freeform.

I saw nothing about this in the documentation.

So here's a short demonstration on how I want this to work:

Freeform form > User submits form > Form is uploaded as a Channel Entry and marked as "Unpublished" > Admin changes status of channel entry and the entry is live on site.

Possible?  Thank you!

Comment: What does freeform offer over channel form?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [freeform_module_insert_end](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/extension_hooks/#freeform_module_insert_end) hook, which gives you access to all of the data posted via the form (and also the ability to retrieve that final data from the Freeform database via the form's entry_id if you like).

Then inside of that hook method, you can use that data to build your entry, which you can then pass to the [Channel Entries API](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_entries.html).